# Is there a way to handle 3 level checkboxes with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following ko markup which are two nested ol with checkboxes

```
<label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue:true, checked: selectAll" />Check all</label>

<ol data-bind="foreach: Itemsnum">
    <li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue:true, checked: selectedOptionnum" />
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></label></li>
    <ol style="margin-left:10px" data-bind="foreach: $parent.Itemsabc">
      <li style="margin-left:10px"><label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue:true,checked: selectedOptionabc"/>
      <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></label></li>

    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

and this is my model

```
var viewModel = new
function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Itemsnum = [
        { Name: 'Option 1',
        Value: 'o1'},
        { Name: 'Option 2',
        Value: 'o2'},
    {
        Name: 'Option 3',
        Value: 'o3'},
    {
        Name: 'Option 4',
        Value: 'o4'}
    ];
     self.Itemsabc = [
        { Name: 'Option a',
        Value: 'oa'},
        { Name: 'Option b',
        Value: 'ob'},
    {
        Name: 'Option c',
        Value: 'oc'},
    {
        Name: 'Option d',
        Value: 'od'}
    ];
    self.selectedOptionnum = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectedOptionabc = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectAll = ko.observable();
   /* self.selectAll = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Itemsnum, function(item) {
                return item.selectedOptionnum() == false;
            });
            return firstUnchecked == null;
        },
        write: function(value) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Itemsnum, function(item) {
                item.selectedOptionnum(value);
            });
        }
    });*/
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I tried to adapt the following example http://jsfiddle.net/romanych/aGFmQ/  and propagate the checked behavior between parents but I get errors. I want to have all the cheked boxed checked, when checked all is clicked and for option[number] all the related option[abc].
Anyone has a clue ? thanks

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwjwxb5h/)

Comment: Is this the behavior you want to create? http://jsfiddle.net/m9c0dtoa/ If it is, I'll take some time to write up an answer explaining how I prototyped it and the benefits/drawbacks.

Comment: Yes, that is the behaviour I as looking for !

Comment: @user3297291, I am trying to replicate the same exact behaviour, I opened a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809102/knockout-checked-binding-and-select-all-children-collection?noredirect=1#comment64987892_38809102 with no luck since my input is different. Also, not sure I get the logic behind (I am quite new to KO). Could you please explain?

Comment: I noticed somebody else already wrote an answer explaining what I did in the fiddle (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38817149/3297291) Let me know if there're still things unclear.