# Knockout checked binding and select all children collection

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Knockout component which template prints two nested lists of items (checkboxes in my interface): a first foreach loop iterates through some "parents" items, a second (and nested) list iterates through each of the parents items and, if children are found, prints the children. The requirement is that if the user clicks on a parent item (that is, on a parent checkbox), all the children checkboxes become checked.

In my code, both parents and children checkboxes listen to an observable that is first set to false and then, when a parent is selected, is set to true - result: that parent's children get selected. 
My issue is that, this way, since every checkbox listen to the same observable, I end up with ALL the checkboxes selected, not only my selected parents + children, which is what I want.

Not sure how I should approach this issue some other way, here is my code:

```
ko.components.register("types",{ 
viewModel: function(){
var self = this;

// Data
self.types = ko.observableArray();
self.isPChecked = ko.observable(false);
nut.structuredDocumentTypes()
  .done(function (types) {
    self.types(types);
  });

// Behaviours
self.selectChildren = function(parent) {
  self.isPChecked(true);
  console.log(self.isPChecked(),parent);
}
},
template: 
'<div id="doctypes" class="wfp-form wfpTreeList">\
  <h2 class="hidden">Document Types</h2>\
  <ul class="wfpList" data-bind="foreach: types">\
    <!-- ko if: $index() > 0 -->\
    <li class="root">\
      <input\
        type="checkbox"\
        name="types"\
        class="wfp-checkbox"\
        data-select="multi"\
        data-bind="\
          checked: $component.isPChecked,\
          event: { change: $component.selectChildren },\
          value: $data.id">\
      <input\
        type="checkbox"\
        name="acc"\
        data-bind="\
          attr: { class: \'lvl\' + $data.id, id: \'acc\' + $data.id }">\
      <label\
        data-bind="attr: { for: \'acc\' + $data.id }">\
          <i class="ico-angle-down"></i>\
      </label>\
      <span data-bind="text: $data.label" class="root-title"></span>\
      <ul data-bind="attr: { \'data-lvl\': \'lvl\' + $index(), id: \'lvl\' + $data.id }">\
        <!-- ko foreach: $data.members -->\
          <li>\
            <label data-bind="attr: { for: \'dt-child-\' + $parent.id + \'-\' + $index() }">\
              <input\
                name="types"\
                type="checkbox"\
                data-bind="\
                  checked: $component.isPChecked,\
                  value: $data.id,\
                  attr: { id: \'dt-child-\' + $parent.id + \'-\' + $index() }">\
              <span data-bind="text: $data.label"></span>\
            </label>\
          </li>\
        <!-- /ko -->\
      </ul>\
    </li>\
  <!-- /ko -->\
  </ul>\
</div>'
});
```

**UPDATE:**
JSON looks like this:

```
[{
"id": 4,
"members": [
    {
        "last_modified_date": "2016-08-04T14:59:25.958Z",
        "id": 31,
        "label": "Backgrounders & Information Notes"
    },
    {
        "last_modified_date": "2016-08-04T14:59:25.961Z",
        "id": 32,
        "label": "Biographies"
    },
],
"label": "Event-/Stakeholder related documentation",
},
{
"id": 2,
"members": [
    {
        "last_modified_date": "2016-08-04T14:59:25.875Z",
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Books"
    },
    {
        "last_modified_date": "2016-08-04T14:59:25.878Z",
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Briefs, Summaries, Synthesis, Highlights"
    },
],
"label": "Publications"
}]
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Have a look at the Fiddle in the first comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724919/is-there-a-way-to-handle-3-level-checkboxes-with-knockout

Comment: Thannks Roy J, that is exactly the behaviour I am looking for. I have a slightly different input though, I will try to change the code to suit my needs. Thanks!

Comment: Not really getting the logic behind it. Also, I have updated my question with my JSON, which is slightly different. Any inputs that can enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should slightly prepare your data by extending doctypes with `computed` property that depends on the state of respective members. Also members should contain `observable` property to track their *checked* state.

The best place to implement such *preparations* will be (I guess) the callback where you initialize `types` property with decoded JSON response:

```
nut.structuredDocumentTypes()
    .done(function (types) {
        // we'll prepare types here
        self.types(types);
    });
```

So using the approach from the fiddle mentioned by **Roy J** (and authored by **user3297291**) in comments you will get something like:

```
nut.structuredDocumentTypes()
    .done(function (types) {

        types.forEach(function(type){
            type.members.forEach(function(member){
                member.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
            });
            type.isSelected = ko.computed({
                read: function(){
                    return type.members.every(function(member){
                        return member.isSelected();
                    });
                },
                write: function(selected){
                    type.members.forEach(function(member){
                        member.isSelected(selected);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        self.types(types); // insert prepared data
    });
```

The code is copied from my fiddle where I'd decomposed your component to the usual view model, and property names are different. Pay your attention to changes in `data-bind` attributes too!

https://jsfiddle.net/ostgals/z8vshLow/

Comment: this really helped me a lot and the approach is way more clean than the fiddle suggested before. Thanks mate.

Comment: (Creator of said suggested fiddle here) While I do agree with you that this answer is very clear and well written, I _would_ like to say that the approach f_martinez took (and credited me for) is basically the exact approach I coded in the fiddle. The confusing parts of the fiddle are the recursiveness, composition and other secondary requirements. The core part, which is the writable computed that lets you read/write selection state, follows the same principle.